# How to display a random message from a text file?

Tags: javascript, html

What I wanted to achieve was to have a random message displayed on the Web page after user clicks a button. I have a list of messages saved in a simple text file, each message on its own line.

Comment: You can't access the user's file system in any useful way in a browser. If you need to do this in the browser, you would have to have the user upload the file. In any case, it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - read local text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)

Comment: Is the file on the user pc or the server? In the latter case, just use XHR, in the former use an input element with a FileReader.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Node.js this will work using the `Filesystem API`. If you are on a local web page the browser won't allow you to do this of safety reasons.

Here is an example of the `Filesystem API`

```
 var fs = require("fs");
 fs.writeFile("path/to/file", "Text", function(error){

 });
```